# ToggleClass on multiple elements with similar class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class, toggle

I've got a navigation with links, that contain the same classes as the sections of the page. See HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="one">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="two">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" class="three">Link 3</a>

<section class="one">Section 1</section>
<section class="two">Section 2</section>
<section class="three">Section 3</section>
```

Now I want to add class 'active' to both the link and the section when I click the link. I've got this working with the following jQuery:

```
$('a').click(function(){

    $('.active').removeClass('active');

    var activeClass = this.className;

    $('.' + activeClass).toggleClass('active');

});
```

The only problem is that the classes don't toggle. I want the active state to disappear for both the link and the section, when I click an active link. I tried it with the if statement this way:

```
if($(this).hasClass('active')){
    var activeClass = this.className;
    $('.' + activeClass).removeClass('active');
}
```

I guess I'm missing some deeper knowledge here, can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6qSdh/)

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to do. First you said you wanted to add 'active' class to both link and section when you click the link. and then you said you want to remove 'active' class when you click the link. The two statements contradict each other.

Comment: No they don't contradict, I want an active link to be unactive when I click it again. That's what isn't working with the code above. Adeneo's answer helped me out. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to exclude the currently clicked class from the `removeClass` statement, otherwise `toggleClass` will always add the class as you always remove it first.

You should also remove the `active` from the `className` when you get it, otherwise you're sometimes getting `one active` etc. and not just `one`.

```
$('a').click(function(){

    var activeClass = '.' + $.trim(this.className.replace('active',''));

    $('.active').not(activeClass).removeClass('active');

    $(activeClass).toggleClass('active');

});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6qSdh/6/)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to rework your script a bit..

```
<style>
a.active{

    color: red


}

section{

    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
}

section.active{

    border-color: red!important;
}


</style>


<a href="#" class="one active">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="two">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" class="three">Link 3</a>

<section class="one active">Section 1</section>
<section class="two">Section 2</section>
<section class="three">Section 3</section>






<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 

        $('a').on('click', function(){

        //remove all active
        $('.active').removeClass('active');

       //get the class of this link
        var activeClass = $(this).attr('class');

        $('.' + activeClass).addClass('active');

    });//end a.bind

});//end doc.ready

<script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7Q4ph/10/